# Alignment inside the table in tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, columns

I created a table, but the last column is moved to the left, although I set it as central. I cannot find what I am doing wrong, so if someone can suggest me how I can solve my problem I would be very grateful.
Below is my latex code and the screenshot what it is generating

```
\documentclass{article}[11pt]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newcolumntype{G}{>{\columncolor{black!5}\centering\arraybackslash} m{5.5cm} } 
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash} m{1.8cm} } 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
    \begin{center}
    \taburulecolor{black!20}
    \begin{tabular}{G : C | C | C |}%| C |}
        %\toprule
        \cline{3-4}
             \multicolumn{2}{C |}{}  & \cellcolor{blue!25}\sf Incomes & \cellcolor{blue!25} \sf Education \\[10pt]
        \cline{1-4}
        \rowcolor{black!5}\multirow{2}{*}{\sf  Test 1}  &\textsf{p-value} & \textsf{1.0} & \textsf{0.0} \\[10pt]
        \cline{2-4}
                                            &\textsf{D} & \sf 0.0  & \sf 0.1904  \\[10pt]
        \hline
        \rowcolor{black!5}\multirow{2}{*}{\sf Test 2}   &\textsf{p-value} & \sf 0.0 & \sf 0.0 \\[10pt]
        \cline{2-4}
                                        &\textsf{P} & \sf 0 & \sf 0.8 \\[10pt]
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\caption{Text}
\label{table:table1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The column types `G`, `:` and `C` are all undefined by default so your example is no help at all and your question is about code you have not shown. Please fix the example to be a complete document that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added the definitions of G and C. Now, I think the code contains everything. The problem appears after compile. This table is a part of a very large document, so I cannot complete all code, but I think now it is very easy to fast create a document to compile.

Comment: @Ziva: Please create a stand-alone, compilable document rather than code snippets. From the looks of it, one might need [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), [`multirow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow), [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) and [`tabu`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu), but even then you still need a definition for the column rule `:`. Help us to help you.

Comment: @Ziva: Please see how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: @Ziva it doesn't contain everything, no one can run it, please fix it so that it generates an example of the problem.

Comment: @Mico Well, but it is a valid syntax.

Comment: @Werner I edited the post - I created a full file which can be compiled. I also posted the screen of the document after compilation. You can see that the values in last column are in bed positions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I posted a full code, which can be compiled and also the screen of the generated file in case you don't know how to do that.

Comment: Off-topic: don't use two-letter font switches in LaTeX documents. The new ones have been around for 20+ years and those are obsolete. Use e.g. `\sffamily` or `\textsf{}` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The additional space forced between the lines seems problematic. It works better if you change `\arraystretch` instead. However, this causes the text in the left-most column to be overwritten by the colour of the next row. This can be avoided by setting the text in the next row with the number of rows passed to `\multirow` given as a negative, rather than positive, number.

Although this works, I do not recommend it because it depends on the use of `tabu`. `tabu` has various bugs which will not be fixed until the next update. This will break existing documents and no support will be provided in the form of a backwards-compatibility option. Only use `tabu` if you do not care that your documents will break suddenly at some point, possibly when you least expect it and could most do without it.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
% \usepackage{tabu}

\newcolumntype{G}{>{\columncolor{black!5}\centering\arraybackslash}m{5.5cm}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.8cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
  \centering
%   \taburulecolor{black!20}
  {\sffamily
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{2}%
  \begin{tabular}{G : C | C | C |}%| C |}
    %\toprule
    \cline{3-4}
    \multicolumn{2}{C |}{}  & \cellcolor{blue!25} Incomes & \cellcolor{blue!25}  Education \\
    \cline{1-4}
    \rowcolor{black!5}  & p-value & 1.0 & 0.0 \\
    \cline{2-4}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{  Test 1} & D &  0.0  &  0.1904  \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{black!5}   & p-value &  0.0 &  0.0 \\
    \cline{2-4}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{ Test 2} & P &  0 &  0.8 \\
%   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}
\caption{Text}
\label{table:table1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Coloured cells do not work well with `booktabs` rules and the use of `\hline` and `\cline` as well as `\bottomrule` and `\toprule` is always going to look odd anyway, so I've commented out the `\bottomrule`. If you want `booktabs` rules, read the documentation and follow the guidelines, sticking exclusively to that package's rules. Otherwise, stick to `\hline` and `\cline`. Obviously, you'll want to have a policy for your document so that all tables are formatted in a consistent way.

[image: fixed up (partially) table]